# Applying Recency In Logistic Regression

Tags: regression, logistic

Are there any statistical concepts or theories on how to effectively measure recency to where recent events are given more weight than older ones. I'm creating a logistic regression model and would like to apply an adjustment to various factors based on the events recency.

...or, is it purely up to me to come up with an arbitrary formula?

For example: One of my projects is predicting via logistic regression the performance of pro golfers in upcoming tournaments. Their recent form (how they played last week) is generally more important than how they played six months ago. Are there any specific techniques/approaches that tap into this concept?

Comment: It will help people answer your question if you could provide more detail on why you want to do this.

Comment: I provided an example from one of my projects.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't necessarily have to be arbitrary; you could, for example, assume exponential discounting and look for the coefficient that has the best predictive value.

That is, at time $t$ you might say that the weight, $w_{t-k} \propto p^k$ or equivalently $w_{t-k} \propto \exp{(-\alpha k)}$ 
(where $0<p<1$ and $\alpha>0$).

In the above, $p$ or $\alpha$ are free parameters, but rather than choose them arbitrarily, you can compare their predictive performance across different values of $p$ (or equivalently, across different $\alpha$), perhaps via comparing sums of squares of one step ahead prediction errors, or whatever other criterion (loss function) you regard as most valuable/interesting/useful.

Alternatively you could use a similar approach but where you apply some other form of discounting, such as [hyperbolic discounting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_discounting#Formal_model).

Comment: I've been out of town but your answer was helpful. Thank you. Doing some digging now...

Comment: See also '[exponential smoothing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing)'.